# Ionic: Build failes when adding angularfirebase2 to app.module.ts file

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

Iam strugling to make angulafirebase2 work in my Ionic project.I simpli follow instructions on instalation/setup for Ionic3 [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md)

And when i add the `import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';` in my app.module.ts file and hit ionic cordova build, i get the error shown in pic below:
[image]

And if i comment out the line for import angulafirebase2, App build successeded....

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
"@backand/angular2-sdk": "^1.2.13",
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.5",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
"autoprefixer": "^7.2.5",
"com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.1.11",
"cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
"cordova-ios": "4.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
"cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~2.4.3",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-windows": "4.4.2",
"firebase": "^4.9.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
"ionic2-numericpicker": "^1.3.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"jQuery": "^1.7.4",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"ngx-clipboard": "^9.1.3",
"promise-polyfill": "7.0.2",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"save": "^2.3.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "0.6.26"
```

},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1"
  },

Answer (score 0):

with Ionic (3 etc) you should be careful about the version of typescript you are using.

In your package.json lock the version to 2.4.2:
"typescript": "2.4.2"

And perform downgrade (through npm update after modifying the package.json)

Try this please. Should fix your problem.

See this guide to ensure your dependencies are in good spot:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516

I also copied below what I have in devdependency in one of my apps:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.2",
"ionic": "^3.19.0",
"typescript": "2.4.2"
```

},